# Is there a way to group date from two different columns and across rows based on other conditions using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date-difference

I am new to pandas and have tried a bit of sorting/filtering and grouping datasets using pandas. I tried to search the forum to find a solution for a problem I am currently facing and couldn't find the right one.

The problem is something like this:

I have a dataset containing two date columns and based on certain conditions on other columns, I need to group these dates together For Eg: This is the input dataset I have

[Input  Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1qa7.png)

Based on values in Columns Con1 and Con2, I need to pick the first start date (Date1) and the last ending date (Date2) and generate the output

The desired output is as follows:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0yZV.png)

I need to group the data as follows: for each unique ID, Col1 and Col2 combination, I need the oldest date (from Date1) and the latest date (from Date2)

In the sample provided ID 13440, C , 1 is the first combination for which I needed to take the date1 from first record ( 10-01-2020 ) and date2 from the last record ( 31-05-2020 ).

Wanted to know if pandas has a easy way for such problems. Sorry for not providing any code I have tried as I am not that proficient in pandas and currently trying the hardway using excel.

Thank you all

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the criteria you want to use to filter this dataset? It's not clear to me how you arrive at your desired output. Also, please take the time to format your question without pictures. It is much easier to read that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas `groupby` can help you get your desired result. In just one line, you can do something like this:

```
data_df.groupby(['ID','Con1','Con2']).agg(Date1=('Date1','first'),
                                     Date2 = ('Date2', 'last')).reset_index().sort_values(by=['Con2','Date1'])
```

And your result will be:

```
    ID    Con1 Con2   Date1     Date2
1   13440   C   1   2020-01-10  2020-05-31
2   13440   C   2   2020-06-01  2020-08-25
0   13440   B   2   2020-08-26  2020-09-15
3   13440   S   2   2020-09-16  2020-10-31
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve and combine the first and last rows in each date column.

```
df1 = (pd.concat([df.groupby(['ID','Con1','Con2'])['Date1'].agg('first'),
                 df.groupby(['ID','Con1','Con2'])['Date2'].agg('last')], axis=1))
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1.sort_values('Date1', ascending=True)
    ID  Con1    Con2    Date1   Date2
1   13440   C   1   2020-01-10  2020-05-31
2   13440   C   2   2020-06-01  2020-08-25
0   13440   B   2   2020-08-26  2020-09-15
3   13440   S   2   2020-09-16  2020-10-31
```

Comment: just curious to know why do we have the third record with index 0 ?

Comment: This is the result of the alphabetical indexing when grouped together. You can use `groupby(...,sort=False)` to get the original order.